# Some SSAS attribute hierarchies take a long time to resolve

Tags: ssas, pivot-table

**Background**
I have developed a SSAS cube that works well for most of my organization's purposes.  The primary method of users interacting with this cube is via Excel Pivot Tables.

**The Issue**
Some of the Pivot Tables created by users have attributes for which their attribute hierarchies take a long time to resolve when the user first clicks on the drop-down box over the field name in the Pivot Table.  For instance, the first time a user clicks the drop-down for a field called "Location - County", it takes ~45 seconds for the pop-up box with the list of ~40 counties to show up.
*Side Note 1*: If I had to guess, it actually seems like SSAS is resolving all field hierarchies in the PT at the same time as the first field that was clicked on because right after this initial resolve, the user can click on any of the fields in the PT and they resolve instantly.  Said another way, the first field clicked on always takes ~45 seconds to resolve.
*Side Note 2*: The next time the user clicks on any of the field drop downs, it resolves almost instantly which I am assuming is because of caching.

**The question**
Why does it take SSAS so long to resolve some attribute hierarchy lists?  It seems to me like this should always be instantaneous?! Doesn't SSAS build all attribute hierarchy lists ahead of time (i.e. during cube processing)?

Many thanks for any light you can shed on this issue for me.

Regards, Jon

---

1/20/15 Update: Adding Trace Files per Request: [Zipped Trace Files](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/fa04d287-11f6-4c92-945b-cd91417b4515/cS91AfMw7ujsFa0HgEyn0g2). I included all EventClasses just to be sure, but if you need me to run again with only the EventClasses requested below I could.

- "Trace of DAR Cubes Project - Test (from service restart).trc" - I restarted AS and immediately refreshed my PT, and recorded the traced events in this file.
- "Trace of DAR Cubes Project - Test (after one refresh).trc" - After refreshing the Excel PT as described above, I closed Excel, reopened the same PT, and refreshed again.  I expected a much faster refresh, but was surprised with almost the same ~35 second wait.  If I keep Excel open between refreshes, it only takes ~2 seconds.  This makes me wonder if Excel is caching the results somehow?  Which would be weird b/c I thought all the logic and caching took place on the server side.

Comment: Could you please create a Profiler trace (with Query Subcube Verbose and Resource Usage events) before the 1st click and attach here the result?

Comment: will also be helpful to add the query-end events so you can get an idea of the queries generated by Excel ;-)